# Does Mongodb automatically disconnect when the Node server closes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connection

I just started using MongoDB. One of my confusions is, I hear it is good to have your MongoDB connection open on initiation and re-use that connection throughout your application.

However, should I ever explicitly close the MongoDB connection eventually? Or does MongoDB implicitly close the connection when the Node server goes down?

Answer (score 1):

unless explicitly closed, the connection will be kept open in the event loop until the process terminates.  So if you intend your app to maintain an open connection to mongodb throughout its life cycle, then there is no need to explicitly close it. It will happen automatically when the process is terminated.

now if you're writing a command script, then you should close the connection explicitly otherwise the open socket will keep your process from terminating.